# Crossing symmetry for mediators

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

The principle of crossing symmetry holds for all interactions.

Consider the reaction: $+→+$

If one of the particles is swapped between the right and left sides of the reaction, it turns into its corresponding antiparticle.

The crossed reaction is still a possible reaction, unless kinematic constraints make it impossible.

When mediators such as $g,\gamma , Z^0$ are swapped between the right and left they stay the same.

Is this true for $W^+$ and $W^-$?

Does the W bosons stay the same when swapped between the right and left.

Answer (score 2):

Why would they? Ignoring the fact, that a W-boson quickly decays, let's take

$$p \rightarrow n + W^+$$

as an example. Already from charge conservation it should be obvious, that the crossed process must be

$$p + W^- \rightarrow n$$

You already stated the reason yourself:

> it turns into its corresponding antiparticle

In case you were confused, that other gauge bosons don't change, that is, because they are their own antiparticle. Do note however, while photons and Z-bosons are uncharged, gluons are colour charged. That charge will change as well under crossing-symmetry.